# Why I didn't got a ip address and internet access after configuring network adapter to 'bridged' in vbox?

Tags: virtualization

My sole purpose is for pentest in a safer virtual environment. But for that I must configure adapter to be bridged. So, what can i do to achieve both (a ip address & internet access). I am using two VMs( kali and Windows xp).

Comment: Better you configure static same DNS ip of XP system to  Kali virtual box

Comment: @Techie can you please explain how can i do this?

Comment: How is using a bridged adapter safer than a host-only network between VM's? If you use a host-only network, the chances of some malware getting out are much greater.

Comment: @mark I know that. But If I choose 'host -only' I will get only ip address not internet access but I want both.

Answer (score 0):

Once kali terminal is opened

Given ip will varies according your setup. Please change it before you add

vi /etc/network/interfaces ( use vi editor )
Inside that

```
auto eth0
address 192.168.1.6
gateway 192.168.1.1
network 192.168.1.0
Netmask 255.255.255.0
Broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

Press ESC from keyboard which exit from vi editor

Type  `wq`  enter

Wq means write and quit

Go to `vi /etc/resolv.conf`

```
Nameserver 8.8.8.8
Nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

ESC button again type `wq` enter

**Nameserver I nothing but your XP system dns**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

To apply the changes made. You have restart your network adaptor.

Type in terminal `Ifconfig` check the DNS and ip address has been assign